# Zeemote js1 connection

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, connection

How do I connect a Zeemote js1 to a raspi and have it control an emulator?
Picture: [image]

Comment: I'm running raspbian

Comment: The zeemote appears to be a bluetooth device. So a USB bluetooth dongle should work. What type of emulator, what are you trying to control, can it be controlled by a mouse?

Comment: @Steve Retro arch is what I'm trying to use